# Conditional formatting based on number of days to due date

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, conditional

In SharePoint 0365, in the modern experience, I have a list of
contracts that have an expiration date.

I would like to use conditional formatting to create a status
column that shows me the contract is one of these:

1. **Active, Green background** - due date is more than 4 month from today.
2. **Expiring, Orange background** - due date is between 4 month from today and today.
3. **Expired, Red background** - due date is past one day.

I'm trying to get this for while now without success. I matched the formulas in Excell where they're working.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$DueDate] > @now + 1036800000 ,'green', (if([$DueDate] - @now >= 0, '#ffa59b','red'))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if([$DueDate] > @now + 1036800000 ,'Current', (if([$DueDate] >= @now - 10368000000, 'Expiring','Expired'))",
      "style": {
        "color": "white"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the result I get:

[image: SharePoint library screen capture]

Here is the working formula tested in Excel, I'm trying to convert in JSON : =IF(B16>TODAY()+120,"green",IF(B16-TODAY()>=0,"orange","red"))  where B16 is the cell containing the contract due date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below and let me know

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$DueDate]>(@now +10368000000), 'Green', if([$DueDate]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +10368000000), 'Expiring', 'Expired'))",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$DueDate]>(@now +10368000000), 'Green', if([$DueDate]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +10368000000), 'Orange', 'Red'))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

[image]

The explanation below may help others understand the `if` conditional formula better.

The formula is an [Excel-style conditional expression](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-conditional-formulas-ca916c57-abd8-4b44-997c-c309b7307831) ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-conditional-formatting)) which is comprised of:

1. `logical_test`:  the condition that you want to check
2. `value_if_true`:  the value to return if the condition is `True`
3. `value_if_false`:  the value to return if the condition is `False`

[image]

In regards to the usage of `@now` and the large numbers, `@now` is a special value which resolves to the current date/time and is evaluated when the user loads the list view ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#formatting-an-item-when-a-date-column-is-before-or-after-todays-date-advanced)).

You can add milliseconds to any date and the result will be a new date.

For example, to add a day to a date, you'd add (`24*60*60*1000 = 86,400,000`) milliseconds ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#formatting-items-based-on-arbitrary-dates-advanced)).

`10,368,000,000` milliseconds is equal to `120 days` or `~ 4 months`.

**Condition 1**

```
if([$DueDate]>(@now +10368000000), 'Green'...
```

If `DueDate` is more than 120 days in the future, set the background color to `Green`.

**Condition 2**

```
if([$DueDate]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +10368000000), 'Orange', 'Red'
```

If `DueDate` is between tomorrow and 120 days in the future, set the background color to `Orange`.

Otherwise (ie if `DueDate` is today or in the past), set the background color to `Red`.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you. For any reason my Sharepoint Document Library, I was working on, got corrupted. Whatever formatting I was trying to apply wouldn't work, including yours.
I created a new library from scratch and now it works this time, all the JSON, including mine (which does contain some errors though).
Your input helped me a lot.

Comment: JSON formatting shouldn't corrupt the library as you can remove it anytime. Is your library not accessible even after removing the JSON format? This might be a different issue here. You can post the issue to the forum as a separate issue.

Comment: Well it's now too late as I discarded the Document Library. There wasn't any error apart that the formatting would not show anything. The column was remaining white.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a full status indicator by merging 2 JSON codes. I must admit my knowledge and experience with JSON is weak. I thought I could go around with Excel knowledge but, no. I will post a new question.